# Permission Error when trying to create tunnel to MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, ssh, putty, workbench

I'm trying to use putty to create a tunnel to a MySQL DB and then use that tunnel to connect to the DB using workbench. When I start putty and check the logs I get `the following error message 2015-10-15 17:55:13    Local port 3306 forwarding to`192.100.1.199:3306 failed: Network error: Permission denied
But when I view the sql statement for the port for the mysql DB I get

```
    SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
```

The thing is I can connect to 192.100.1.199 VM and the hostname for the DB is also 192.100.1.199. Does anyone why this might fail on permissions.

Comment: Can you connect to the host via SSH without port-forwarding?

Comment: Yes if I ssh using mysql -uuser -ppwassword

Comment: Err, I'm not sure what you just said there. Can you connect via SSH to the host (ignoring MySQL for now)?

Comment: Sorry, yes I can, I also get a successful connection in the putty  logs

Comment: But not with the port forwarding / tunnel? What does your tunnel config look like? Are you perhaps already running something locally on port 3306? Maybe try a different local (source) port like 5000 or something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you might already have something locally bound to port 3306. I suggest you use a different local port (say 5000) so you end up with

```
L5000 192.100.1.199:3306
```

Then connect via `localhost:5000`.

---

Were you able to directly use `ssh`, you would have seen an error message similar to

> bind: Address already in use
>  
>   channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 3306
>   Could not request local forwarding.

which is probably a lot more informative than what you were getting out of PuTTY :)